# WSO2 APIM 3.0.0 : Unable to SIGN-IN from /publisher and /devportal after installing certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have installed WSO2 API Manager version: 3.0.0 and it is working fine with *localhost* and as well as with different hostname though it shows *Not secure* site on address bar.
But when we install valid CA signed certificate and update *deployment.toml* file with primary keystore details it throws below error on server startup

```
TID: [-1] [] [2020-05-14 19:40:56,552]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever} - Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <*.example.com> OR <*.example.com> OR <example.com>. Retrying after 15 seconds...
TID: [-1] [] [2020-05-14 19:40:57,425]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.jwt.RevokedJWTTokensRetriever} - Failed retrieving revoked JWT token signatures from remote endpoint: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <*.example.com> OR <*.example.com> OR <example.com>. Retrying after 15 seconds...
TID: [-1] [] [2020-05-14 19:40:57,748]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.BlockingConditionRetriever} - Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <*.example.com> OR <*.example.com> OR <example.com>. Retrying after 15 seconds...
```

*Note*- here, i have replaced actual domain name with *example* in above log statements due to privacy policy

After server startup, we are able to access *management console* and */devportal*, But when we try to access */publisher* or SIGN-IN from with in *devportal* it throws 500 error.

Without certificate and no change to *keystore.primary* in *deployment.toml*
[image: without certificate]

With certificate and added *keystore.primary* into *deployment.toml*
[image: with certificate]

we see the below SSL error when we try to access /Publisher or SIGN-IN from /devportal

```
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-05-15 19:12:43,562] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost (<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220) org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost (<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:289)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:589)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost (<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js#220)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<<http>>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_5(<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:220)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<<http>>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<<http>>.META_INF.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_7(<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js:228)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<<http>>.META_INF.scripts.c0.call(<<http>>/META-INF/scripts/http.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag:35)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.call(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.services.login.c0.exec(/publisher/services/login/idp.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:583)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.executeRequest(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:572)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:549)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:301)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.executeRequest(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:555)
    ... 72 more
```

Here is my *deployment.toml* file

```
[server]
hostname = "example.com"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database"

[database.apim_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "keystore.jks"
type =  "PKCS12"
password =  "mypassword"
alias =  "1"
key_password =  "mypassword"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}"

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

#[apim.analytics]
#enable = false
#store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#event_publisher_type = "default"
#event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
#publish_response_size = true

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7611","tcp://analytics2:7611"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7711","ssl://analytics2:7711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7612","tcp://analytics2:7612"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7712","ssl://analytics2:7712"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.key_manager]
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://example.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.15/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.15/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"
```

Below is the *wrapper.conf* used to start wso2 as a service. placed this file under *yajsw-stable-12.14\conf*

```
#********************************************************************
# working directory
#********************************************************************
wrapper.working.dir=${CARBON_HOME}/
# Java Main class.
# YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain"
# DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION
# wrapper.java.mainclass=
#********************************************************************
# tmp folder
# yajsw creates temporary files named in_.. out_.. err_.. jna..
# per default these are placed in jna.tmpdir.
# jna.tmpdir is set in setenv batch file to <yajsw>/tmp
#********************************************************************
wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}
#********************************************************************
# Application main class or native executable
# One of the following properties MUST be defined
#********************************************************************
# Java Application main class
wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}\/log\/wrapper.log
# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
#wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
#wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling by size.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kB) or
#  'm' (mB) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
# If wrapper.logfile does not contain the string ROLLNUM it will be automatically added as suffix of the file name
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m
# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=WSO2 APIM Carbon
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Service and Posix Daemon Properties
#********************************************************************
# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=WSO2APIMCARBON
# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=WSO2 APIM Carbon
# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=Carbon Kernel
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper System Tray Properties
#********************************************************************
# enable system tray
wrapper.tray = true
# TCP/IP port. If none is defined multicast discovery is used to find the port
# Set the port in case multicast is not possible.
wrapper.tray.port = 15002
#********************************************************************
# Exit Code Properties
# Restart on non zero exit code
#********************************************************************
wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN
wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART
#********************************************************************
# Trigger actions on console output
#********************************************************************
# On Exception show message in system tray
wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception
wrapper.filter.script.0=${wrapper_home}/scripts/trayMessage.gv
wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception
#********************************************************************
# genConfig: further Properties generated by genConfig
#********************************************************************
placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=
wrapper.java.command = ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${CARBON_HOME}/bin/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${CARBON_HOME}/lib/commons-lang-*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3 = ${CARBON_HOME}/lib/*.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN
wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath/a:${CARBON_HOME}/lib/xboot/*.jar
wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m
wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof
wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Dcarbon.registry.root=\/
wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.home=${CARBON_HOME}
wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Dwso2.server.standalone=true
wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Djava.command=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${CARBON_HOME}/tmp
wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Dcatalina.base=${CARBON_HOME}/lib/tomcat
wrapper.java.additional.14 = -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/etc/logging-bridge.properties
wrapper.java.additional.15 = -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf
wrapper.java.additional.16 = -Dcarbon.logs.path=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/logs
wrapper.java.additional.17 = -Dcomponents.repo=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/components/plugins
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dconf.location=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf
wrapper.java.additional.19 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=${CARBON_HOME}/lib/transactions.properties
wrapper.java.additional.20 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true
wrapper.java.additional.21 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
wrapper.java.additional.22 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple
wrapper.java.additional.23 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000
wrapper.java.additional.24 = -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true
wrapper.java.additional.25 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -DworkerNode=false
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=DefaultAndLocalhost
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dcarbon.new.config.dir.path=${CARBON_HOME}/repository/resources/conf
```

Comment: Did u generate a new keystore?

Comment: Hi @Pubci, Yes, we had the .pfx file and using which we have created a keystore.jks of type JKS using the same keystore password as of private key password. Also generated .pem and imported into client-store.jks. Finally configured the latest keystore.jks in deployment.toml.

Comment: @Pubci , I have added more error details when we access /Publisher. same error can be observed when SIGN-IN within /devportal

Comment: It seems all these issues come due to hostname verification. Do you have changes in wso2server.sh?

Comment: @Pubci, No. We have made NO changes into wso2server.bat. We are running apim as a service using yajsw-stable-12.14. and JDK-11. i have updated the post with wrapper.conf also for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

During login APIM makes internal API calls. This error occurs when hostname 'localhost' is used for the API calls but the truststore doesn't have a valid certificate for 'localhost'. Changing the hostname used in the API calls to the hostname configured in the deployment.yaml should resolve this. The internal API calls can be found in the jaggery files in the *[HOME]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/[DEVPORTAL/PUBLISHER]/services* directory. Or else add a SAN to the cert for localhost.

Comment: Hi @Ruwini Wijesiri, there are no files under PUBLIHSER directory having _localhost_ in it. Could you please give more details on the second option SAN? what is it and how to add it.

Comment: Please refer to this link-  https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8435